# What should be naming convention of topic and partition of Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Here are some example I was trying to use for kafka,

I am not sure it is good to go with or any specific naming convention?

For Topic

> 1. {name}_queue
> 2. {name}_topic

- Here I think first option is not good because Topic is not queue exactly.
- In the term of Computer Science Queue means First Come First Out.
- If partitions come into the picture in topic than Topic will be no longer queue because inside the topic partitions is part of queue and data comes from 
  For Partitions

> 1. {name}_partition
> 2. {name}_{kafka topic name}_partition
> 3. {name}_{kafka topic name}_part

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this. All you need to do is to assign a Kafka topic name that adheres to `[a-zA-Z0-9\\._\\-]`. So `like-this` or `like_this` or `likeThis` or even `likethis`. Kafka will handle partition names for you by adding `topic-name-{partitionid}` for each partition.

Answer (score 1):

There is no much written related to Kafka topics naming convention, but [this](https://medium.com/@criccomini/how-to-paint-a-bike-shed-kafka-topic-naming-conventions-1b7259790073) may give you some guidance

Comment: Thanks for this reference. The content on blog post is a good point to start.