# Nats/Jetstream: naming conventions for commands' subjects

Tags: command, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I have been working with Nats/Jetstream for a bit now and within a CQRS/Event sourcing project. Recently, it occurred to me that I have not been following any naming conventions for subjects' names that are used for commands (events are pretty much covered). What have been doing so far is, as follows:

```
myProjectName.internal.pricing
```

Meaning the `myProjectName` as my project name, `internal` as it is internal to a specific service in my project and then ultimately the action performed by that command (e.g. some pricing logic). Are there any widely used naming conventions I can use? I would appreciate if you can share any view or resource I can use to have a better naming across my project.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are good articles about it:

- [Subject-Based Messaging](https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/subjects)
- [Kafka topic naming conventions - 5 recommendations with examples](https://www.kadeck.com/blog/kafka-topic-naming-conventions-5-recommendations-with-examples)
- [Kafka Topic Naming Conventions](https://cnr.sh/essays/how-paint-bike-shed-kafka-topic-naming-conventions)

General recommendations:

- `separate.with.dots.lowercase` - avoid capitalization.
- Keep your subject short. It is recommended to keep the maximum number of tokens in your subjects to a reasonable value of 16 tokens max.
- Create a structure for grouping. The separation by a dot (.) and the structure in the sense of the Reverse Domain Name Notation (reverse-DNS) has proven itself. Prefer Domain Service Names (see [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)).
- Explicitly mark the data as "private" or "public" with a corresponding prefix - "private" is for internal subjects, "public" - for official.

```
public.sales.ecommerce.shoppingcarts
private.risk.portfolio.analysis.loans.csvimport
```

- Suffixing by  can be a good way to indicate in advance how to consume a topic for example `.avro` , `.json`, `.text`, `.protobuf`, `.csv`, `.log`.
- You could prefix JetStream subject: `js.in.orders.>` (where `.in`/`.out` is the prefix for inbound or outbound messages).

**What should be avoided?**

- Appending of a version number - the better way is to add the version number of the used schema as part of the header to the respective record. It is even better to use a schema registry in which all information about the schema, versioning, and compatibility is stored centrally.
- Using application names as part of the topic name.
- Team name/partition numbers or consumer/producer names.
- Namespaces or company names - your colleagues usually know the name of the company where they work

```
public.com.xeotek.sales.ecommerce.shoppingcarts
```

Similar question about Kafka topics best practices: [What is the best practice for naming kafka topics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726571/what-is-the-best-practice-for-naming-kafka-topics)

Comment: Such a brilliant and well articulated answer, thank you so much!